# Preferred direction for laying laminate flooring thorughtout a house?

Tags: flooring, laminate

Can you tell me what is the preferred direction for laying laminate flooring throughout a house?

Comment: If you orient the laminate exactly north/south, then any razor blades in the house will automatically sharpen over time.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it either direction.  I ran mine parallel to the longest wall.  It makes for less cuts.  Make sure your subfloor is level.  My houses was not and gaps appeared over time.  I just recently fixed them from this post [[How to close gaps between laminate floorboards](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58532/how-to-close-gaps-between-laminate-floorboards][1]) .